# xcodebuild gets stuck with literals on test target

Tags: objective-c, testing, literals, xcodebuild

I'm trying to integrate tests on my project but I'm having a problem, as soon I add literals in my testing code, xcodebuild gets stuck without any message. It wait forever with this message:

```
Touch /Users/serluca/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my_app-glgzugfganivsggqoytrqgbvxlhi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCAnalyticsTests.xctest
cd /Users/serluca/Workspace/rc-app
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneSimulator.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Users/serluca/bin"
/usr/bin/touch -c /Users/serluca/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/my_app-glgzugfganivsggqoytrqgbvxlhi/Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator/RCAnalyticsTests.xctest
```

It works if I execute tests from XCode, any suggestion?
This is the command that I'm using:

```
xcodebuild -workspace 'my-workspace' -scheme 'my-scheme' -configuration "Debug" -destination 'platform=iOS Simulator,id=B0059CD3-FE9D-4DBE-9A8A-CBE7EE595D9A' -sdk iphonesimulator9.2 -verbose clean build test
```